# Getting error in Codeigniter: A Database Error Occurred.The query you submitted is not valid

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below is my model code, in which I'm getting a database error:

```
public function getxyz()
{
    $query ='SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(field1,LOCATE('-',field1) - 1)) as field1
    FROM table1';
    $res = $this->db->query($query);
    return $res->result();
}
```

**Note:** This query is running successfully in phpmyadmin.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an error in the query related to the single quotes you are using to enclose the query. They are interfering with the single quotes to the string - seems out of the query. Try this query:

```
 $query ="SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(field1,LOCATE('-',field1) - 1)) as field1
        FROM table1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working fine `PHPMYADMIIN` because there is no issue with quotes around `SQL statement`.

You just need to fix single and double quote issue in your query.

**Example:**

```
public function getxyz()
{
    $query ="SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(field1,LOCATE('-',field1) - 1)) as field1
    FROM table1";
    $res = $this->db->query($query);
    return $res->result();
}
```